# Assembling a compile-time list of types one by one (C++)

Tags: c++

I want to assemble a list (actually: a set) of types at compile-time by adding types one by one. Something like this:

```
struct HeadOfList;

struct Item1;
[ addToList<Item1, HeadOfList> ]

struct Item2;
[ addToList<Item2, HeadOfList> ]
```

I do not care how the list is stored. I think of something like this:

```
template<typename T> struct NextInList { typedef void type; };
template<> struct NextInList<HeadOfList> { typedef Item1 type; };
template<> struct NextInList<Item1> { typedef Item2 type; };
template<> struct NextInList<Item2> { typedef Item3 type; };
```

but a `boost::mpl::list` is just as fine. The order of the types does not matter either, I just want to be able to iterate through them and adding new elements to them.

I have a bad feeling about this, since such a construction would mean that e.g. `LastElementOf<MyList>::type` would compile to different types at different points of the source file (before and after adding a new element), and it seems bogus to me. Nevertheless that is exactly what I want now.

Do you think it is possible somehow? C++11 is allowed.

**Update:** I just want to add that I do not know the last element added to the list at the time of adding a new element, but I know the list itself (e.g. the head of the list)

Comment: Have a look at [typelists](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403813).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've looked into it and the list discussed there didn't seemed to be capable of adding a new element under my constraints (without knowing the current last element of the list)

Comment: What is wrong with boost::mpl::vector. You can use the `push_back` function to add more types.

Comment: The question with `boost::mpl::vector` is how can I 'store' (mark) the result for future use (by use I mean iterating through the list). To put it simple I cannot do the equivalent of this: `mylist := mylist::push_back<Item>::type`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After consulting with comp.lang.c++.moderated I came up with the code detailed below. The `PushBack()` macro is used to add new items to the list, one can iterate through the items by using the `Next()` macro, and the last item can be recognized from that its 'next item' is itself. So a very basic example code:

```
struct A {}; 

namespace NS1 { 
    struct B {}; 
    struct C {}; 
    struct D {}; 

    // building up the compile-time list 
    struct Head; 

    PushBack(Head, A); 
    PushBack(Head, B); 
} 

PushBack(NS1::Head, NS1::C); 

namespace NS1 { 
    PushBack(Head, D); 
} 



// iterate through the list
namespace NS2 { 

    // end of the list reached (recognized from PrevItem == Item)
    template <class ListId, class Item> 
    void print(Wrapper<Item>, Wrapper<Item>) {} 

    // process Item and advance to the next element
    template <class ListId, class PrevItem, class Item> 
    void print(Wrapper<PrevItem>, Wrapper<Item>) 
    { 
        cout << typeid(Item).name() << endl; 
        print<ListId>(Wrapper<Item>(), Wrapper< Next(ListId, Item) >()); 
    } 
}
```

A more detailed example that also contains an iterator to ease the use of the list can be found [here](http://ideone.com/UNDDA) or [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3095355/CompileTimeList.cpp).

The most important part of the 'library':

```
/// Helper class to wrap incomplete types and avoid instantiation of T 
template<class T> struct Wrapper {}; 

namespace CTList { 
    /// The front of compile-time lists 
    struct Nil {}; 
} 

/// Compile-time list helper 
template< typename ListId, typename Item > 
Item NextInListHelper( ::Wrapper<ListId>, ::Wrapper<Item> ); 

/// The last element of the list
#define Back(ListId) \ 
    decltype( NextInListHelper( ::Wrapper<ListId>(), ::Wrapper<\ 
    decltype( NextInListHelper( ::Wrapper<ListId>(), ::Wrapper<\ 
    decltype( NextInListHelper( ::Wrapper<ListId>(), ::Wrapper<\ 
    decltype( NextInListHelper( ::Wrapper<ListId>(), ::Wrapper<\ 
    decltype( NextInListHelper( ::Wrapper<ListId>(), ::Wrapper<\ 
    decltype( NextInListHelper( ::Wrapper<ListId>(), ::Wrapper<\ 
    decltype( NextInListHelper( ::Wrapper<ListId>(), ::Wrapper<\ 
    decltype( NextInListHelper( ::Wrapper<ListId>(), ::Wrapper<\ 
    decltype( NextInListHelper( ::Wrapper<ListId>(), ::Wrapper<\ 
    decltype( NextInListHelper( ::Wrapper<ListId>(), ::Wrapper<\ 
                             CTList::Nil \ 
     >())) \ 
     >())) \ 
     >())) \ 
     >())) \ 
     >())) \ 
     >())) \ 
     >())) \ 
     >())) \ 
     >())) \ 
     >())) 



/// Add a new element (type) to the list 
#define PushBack( ListId, item) \ 
    item NextInListHelper( ::Wrapper< ListId >, ::Wrapper< Back(ListId) > ) 

/// The next element in the ('ListId') list after 'item' 
#define Next(ListId, item) decltype(NextInListHelper(::Wrapper<ListId>(), ::Wrapper<item>() ))
```

It uses `NextInListHelper` function declarations and Argument Dependent (Name)Look-up to record the list. The last element of the list can be referenced using the `Back` macro.

The first element of the list can be accessed as: `Next(ListId, CTList::Nil)`, 
the last element of the list can be recognized from that it is the 
same as its next element (`LastItem == Next(ListId, LastItem)`).

I tested it only with gcc 4.6.3, but it is intended to be fully C++11 compliant.

A few words about the solution:

- in this form it can handle type lists up to 10 elements, but this can be extended by adding extra lines to the `Back()` macro
- the 'list' can contain a type only once
- the additional `ListId` type used in `NextInListHelper` declarations is there to allow types to be contained in multiple lists simultaneously
- `Wrapper` is used to avoid actual instantiation of list element types and to support incomplete types as ListId
- `PushBack()` 'calls' must be in the namespace of `ListId` (`NS1`) or `Wrapper` (the global scope)
- The processing of the list can be put in any namespace (`NS2`)